# How to dynamically define 'path' in @BlobOutput?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I am looking at the following code example at https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker

```
public class MyClass {
    @FunctionName("copy")
    @StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")
    @BlobOutput(name = "$return", path = "samples-output-java/{name}")
    public static String copy(@BlobTrigger(name = "blob", path = "samples-input-java/{name}") String content) {
        return content;
    }
}
```

In `@BlobOutput` we are using `{name}` parameter, because it was provided to us in `@BlobInput`. How can I dynamically generate that name in my function?

I want my blob name to be `files/E36567AB1B93F7D9798` where the `E36567AB1B93F7D9798` part is a hash generated from blob content. I want to generate it inside the function and return the hash as output. Sort of like GitHub creates unique IDs for files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to define a unique and dynamic value for blob name, I recommend you to use `{rand-guid}`. Here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-expressions-and-patterns).

`@BlobOutput(name = "$return", path = "samples-output-java/files/{rand-guid}")`.

You will get a blob named like `85546257-97f8-43ea-961e-a8bbe70e009d` in the virtual directory `files`.

If you have to use hash value of your file content, as for now it's not supported to do that in bindings, you can use Azure Storage SDK inside the function to specify your blob name.

Here's the related [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/85) on github for you to refer.

Comment: thank you, this works. interestingly enough, I cannot use Azure Storage SDK from inside the function. the process hangs when trying to connect to storage. i am in talks with Support to figure out why.

Comment: would you happen to have an example where Azure Storage SDK is used from inside the function?

Comment: @anton1980 Have you got any response from support? Found some samples after googling, but not sure what your problem is exactly. If you don't mind, you can open another question as it's a little difficult to offer detailed answer in comment.